# Control apartment buzzer

Tags: hardware

I have a [Aiphone GT-1C](http://www.aiphone.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/GT-Installation-Operation-Manual.pdf) system and am trying to see if its possible to trigger the door release feature for my apartments intercom system.

[image]

[image]

The pinout reads:

```
    IN  | OUT | IN | OUT |
    ----+-----+----+-----+
    R R |R R  |B B |B B  |
    1 2 |1 2  |1 2 |1 2  |
   23.4v|23.4v| 0v | 0v  |
```

I measured the In and Out for `R1/2` at `23.4v` and `0v` for In and out of `B1/2`. When I press the door release button (when its off not being called) all the pins go to 23.4v high. This leads me to believe that they are sending data over wire. I do have an oscilloscope that I could use but I feel like if it got to that point it would be over my head.

#### Is it easily possible to control the door release function via Raspberry pi?

(I was hoping it would just be turning a pin high and low but sadly it looks more complicated than that and its a 24v logic level)

---

## UPDATE:

So I emailed tech support asking if they had a dedicated door release pin and they responded with this:

> An option switch dry contact closure can be used when connecting a
>   dedicated strike circuit to the gray and black wires of the 6-pin
>   option cable.
>
> The door release button on the GT-1C triggers the Form C contact built
>   into the back of the speaker module of the entrance. The tenant would
>   need to press the Option button (the icon looks like a laptop monitor)
>   to unlock their own unique door.

[image]

Comment: If you're not a qualified [door technician/electrician/other-related-ician], I'd be *very careful* about trying this. Screwing around with door locking mechanisms is likely to do some very bad things to any future insurance claims.

Comment: You could control a servo motor that pushed the actual physical button on the control pad.

Comment: How do you know that b1 and 2 are input and output are you referring to one cable or 4 cables 2 in and two out or?

Comment: This might be something you should explore on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was no real solution I found. I ended up taking the unit apart and soldering contacts onto the breadboard where the push buttons are and use a relay to emulate pressing the button. Works pretty well but still don't have a dedicated switch to open the door.

Comment: I have the same system, would you be able to show pics, and what hardware you went with?

Comment: Could you share a picture of the solution? Really interested in making this work myself